# embedded XNA 4.0 game in WinForm is running too slow, what do I do?

Tags: c#, winforms, xna-4.0, performance

I have an embedded XNA 4.0 game in WinForm (for a level editor). The code is in this format:

in the game class:

```
protected override void Initialize(){
    //initialization logic here  
    base.Initialize();

    SysWinForms.Form gameWindowForm(SysWinForms.Form)SysWinForms.Form.FromHandle(this.Window.Handle);
    gameWindowForm.Shown += new EventHandler(gameWindowForm_Shown);

    MYFORM = new Form1();
    MYFORM.HandleDestroyed += new EventHandler(myForm_HandleDestroyed);
    MYFORM.Show();
}


void myForm_HandleDestroyed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Exit();
}

void gameWindowForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((SysWinForms.Form)sender).Hide(); 
     //this line is important. When this line is commented the XNA + winForm windows are both shown. Also, the xna game is running in the winForm and it is running with modest speed. 
     //but when the line is not commented, than only the winForm window is shown and the xna game is shown inside it, but it is running with 0.5 frames/seconds
}

//The loadContent, unloadContent, update, and game constructor classes remain the same

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
{
     //draw logic here
     base.Draw(gameTime);
        //this is the actual trick that makes it all happen
        this.GraphicsDevice.Present(new Rectangle(controls.panel1.Location.X, controls.panel1.Location.Y, desired_Width, desired_Height), null, this.MYFORM.PanelHandle);
}
```

in the MYFORM class:

```
public IntPtr PanelHandle
{
    get
    {
        return this.panel1.IsHandleCreated ? this.panel1.Handle : IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```

also there is a automatically generated:

```
public System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
```

I will be really grateful if somebody took a look at the code, and especially at the comment in " void gameWindowForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) " function.

thx in advance

Comment: Why are you using winforms with XNA? I believe that this is the typical kind of result you will see if you mix the two as the draw buffers don't play well together. I would suggest using something more like http://xnaml.codeplex.com/

Comment: @sec_goat Actually you've got that backwards. XNA's own internal implementation uses WinForms - and a correct implementation on WinForms suffers no performance penalty. It's WPF that requires complicated buffer setup to avoid a severe performance penalty.

Answer (score 2):

Take it from the expert Shawn Hargreaves http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/01/23/using-xna-with-winforms.aspx

> often see people trying to use the XNA Game class in unusual places,
>   for instance to host an XNA game inside a WinForms application.
>
> That is usually a bad idea.
>
> The Game class is designed to be simple, automatically setting
>   everything up ready for you to start coding. If you are doing
>   something complicated and want more control over the details of how
>   your window is created, this is only going to get in your way.

Microsoft provides code samples [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_1) and [here](http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/sample/winforms_series_2) for setting up the XNA graphics device to use with WinForms.

Comment: Since that blog post was written, a sample to do exactly that (replace the `Game` class) was developed. I've taken the liberty of adding the link to your answer.

Comment: @AndrewRussell Thanks for setting me straight on both counts, I knew I was close, but it's been quiet some time since I've actually used xna.